# Print command python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm new in the python world and i have small issue.
im trying to run this action for example:

```
print ('Hello World')

print('1','2')
```

But i'm getting this output:

```
Hello World

('1','2')
```

Why the second row is not showing properly?

I'm using a mac laptop with python version 2.7

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean with properly? Please give us the expected output. Also you should share your codes in Stack Overflow Community with quotes like this `print ('Hello World')` for avoiding formatted text problems.

Answer (score 1):

Because `()` is used for grouping, it does not have an effect in the execution level but it makes your code look prettier:

```
 if ( 1 > 2 > 3):
```

is totally samw with

```
if 1 > 2 > 3:
```

Most important part is, `(1)` is not a `tuple` with a single element. Those parenthesis are evaluated as grouper, and have no effect in execution so it is totally same with `1`. On the other hand, `(1,)` is a `tuple` and `,` after the first element implies that.

So

```
print ("Hello World")
print "Hello World"
```

are totally the same thing. But `('1','2')` is a tuple so `print` statement prints it.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the Python 3 `print()` function, not the Python 2 `print` command. However, you're trying to use this function in Python 2.  Use `from __future__ import print_function` to get this behavior in Python 2.

See also [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) and [PEP 3105](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/).

Answer (score 0):

`print ('Hello World')` prints the string `Hello World`

`print ('1','2')` prints *the tuple* `('1','2')`.

Comment: Im not sure i get it, i try this :
print('test','koko')
and get this:
('test','koko')  Instead  test koko

Comment: Don't use `(` and `)` with `print` when you're working with Python 2.x. `print '1', '2'` is enough.

Comment: @Matthias - could you edit your answer to explain the difference between `print '1', '2'` and `print('1', '2')` in Python 2.X? It would improve the answer.